# How to go about editing a php file to change values?

Tags: php, xml, security, fopen, fwrite

I would like to write a script to edit a css file or maybe even a slideshow for instance where a form will update the variables in my php document. I've been doing some reading and some say editing a `php` file directly is bad news due to security issues and to use `xml`.

I am not connecting to databases or anything like that. So my question is is this correct to write script to directly write/update a php file to changes its variables?

Thank you.

Comment: I think what you really need is a very, very basic programming course. The first thing every coder learns about programming is how to use these little magic things called `parameters`. Work with them. They're your friends.

Comment: As i see it, his question is mostly about how to save the values he gets.

Comment: I am very familiar with parameters @Renan. I just wanted to know an approach to save my values to the php file not for pushing to a database or the like. If there is a way to do this with parameters could you point in in the right direction? I am in my basic learning stages as I assume you have been here before.

Answer (score 1):

if you can correctly sanitize your input then it is a usable aproach. The worst that can happen is code injection. So do check for variable length and content very strictly. It is like `eval();` only worse, as everyone else will run it to. If there are only variables to change you might consider using an **.ini** file for configuration. And Use the data in that from your PHP script

Answer (score 0):

1. In general you should not run PHP scripts as a user with permissions to write to its own executable code; it means any file write vulnerability immediately escalates to a code execution vulnerability.
2. Writing dynamic data into a PHP file is risky. You would need to know how to serialise/escape any value to a PHP literal exactly; any error could result in code execution. Watertight code generation is in general a tricky thing.

There is almost certainly a better way to approach whatever it is you are doing. Putting data in a static store such as a config file or database, and reading the data at run-time, would seem to be the place to start.